# Term by Term Differentiability in the context of Uniform Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, derivatives, uniform-convergence

I'm not sure how differentiability works with uniform convergence. My book says that we can show this (calculation wise) $$\varepsilon (x,a) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} E_{k}(x,a)$$

for some $x$ and $a$.

In this context, I'm not sure how to go about doing this:

**Prove that $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}+x^{2}}$$ is differentiable for all values of $x$.**

If someone could give me a hand, that would be great. My book has no examples in this topic, so I just chose one of the first questions from it.

(If more context is needed, please let me know. This is my first stackexchange question.)

Comment: Nice job on your first question. The basic theorem here is that if the series and the series of derivatives converge uniformly on an interval, the series is differentiable, with the derivative being the sum of derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot always differentiate term-by-term  but in this case we can. Let $f_n(x)=1/(n^2+x^2)$, let $F_k(x)=\sum_{n=1}^kf_n(x)$ , let $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{k\to \infty}F_k(x).$$  Let $g_k(x)=\sum_{n=1}^kf'_n(x)$ and let $$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f'_n(x)=\lim_{k\to \infty}g_k(x).$$ Now each $g_k$ is continuous. If you can show that $g_k$ converges uniformly  to $g$ on any bounded real set as $k\to \infty$, then you know $g$ is continuous and that $$f(x)-f(a)=\lim_{k\to \infty}(F_k(x)-F_k(a))=\lim_{k\to \infty}\int_a^xg_k(y) dy=\int_a^xg(y)dy$$ for any $x,a.$ Now since $g$ is continuous we have (with any fixed $a\ne x$),$$f'(x)=g(x).$$

Comment: Thank you! I'm a little confused on how you said $g_{k}(x)$ is uniformly convergent. Can you elaborate?

Comment: For $|x|\leq C$ we have $|f'_n(x)|=2|x|/(n^2+x^2)^2\leq 2 C/n^4$ . So  $\forall x\in [-C,C]$ we have convergence as fast as $\sum C/n^4$.

Comment: As an extreme case where this method does not work, there exists a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in N}:R\to [0,1]$ of continuously differentiable functions converging uniformly on $R$ to a continuous $f:R\to [0,1]$ that has no derivative at any point. Of course the sequence $(f'_n)_{n\in N}$ behaves very badly.