# Is it possible to calculate the gradient of a function defined by an infinite sum?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I would put this pretty easy, my questions is about if it is possible to get the gradient of the following function:

---

$$ F(r)=\dfrac{\lambda}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{a^{2(m+1)}}{r^{2(m+1)}(m+1)}$$

And if it is possible, what theorem says it? And how does it calculate?

Comment: That appears to be a function of one variable ($r$), defined by an infinite series that converges absolutely so long as $r$ is sufficiently large (the meaning of "sufficiently large" will depend on $a$).  Differentiate term by term, no?

Comment: Yes, r is so much greater than a, but then the only argument to differentiate term by term is that the infinite serie converges absolutely? Is there any more details to consider? Or what theorem tells you that assumption is true?

Comment: Sorry... it seems that I lied.  [Uniform convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1520348/term-by-term-differentiability-in-the-context-of-uniform-convergence) (of the series, and of the series obtained by term-by-term differentiation) is required.  However, I think that this series converges uniformly where it converges absolutely.  Ditto the term-by-term derivative series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is the Weirstrass-M test. As long as you are defining 
$r\in (-b,b)$ and 
$$
\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{a^{2m+1}}{b^{2m+1}(m+1)}
$$
converges, then you may compute derivatives term by term.